# How can the entire system be at rest irrespective of how much external force you apply?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

**NOTE**: I only wish to understand the underlying concepts and visualization aspects. I do not by an intention mean to seek a complete worked out solution for this answer.

> In the diagram shown, the mass of the [man + block] $A$ is $10$ kg and of block $B$ is $5$ kg. The coefficient of friction under both the blocks is $.3$. The man is firmly( fixed) standing on the block $A$. At $t=0$, the man starts applying force $F$ on the string, which increases acoording to the relation $F=kt$, where $'k'$ is positive constant and $'t'$ denotes time. All pulleys are masseless and frictionless and string is masless and inextensible.
>
> Find out variation of friction forces $f_{r,A}$ and $f_{r,B}$ acting on block $A$ and $B$ respectively, as a function of time. Draw a graph of friction versus time for $f_{r,A}$ and $f_{r,B}$
>
> $\hspace{3cm}$    [image]

Now I was unable to solve this question as I'm unsure whether block A will remain at rest or not. How can judge whether block is at rest or not once $t>15/k$

## My attempt:

I first drew the force diagram

$\hspace{2cm}$ [image]

Then I wrote these steps but ended up like this
$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

I went through sources trying to get a conceptual clarity on tension and friction but is still unable to figure out whether A will be at rest or in motion. I do understand A will be at rest immediately after $t>15/k$ but when lets say at infinite time, the value of $F=kt$ becomes infinitely large. Then wouldn't it overcome the limiting frictional force causing the blocks to move?

Comment: How am I supposed to modify this question for opening?

Comment: For better understanding I assume the $T_1$ tension wire to be slack , when system  A pulls on the wire , it is the friction that opposes motion , once it has crossed its Limiting value then $T_1$ kicks in. so $f_{rb}$ is linear upto $t = 15/k$ then remains constant at $15N$, for system $A$, in your FBD you missed out $F$ force acting rightwards on the man, hence $f_{ra}$ acts leftwards on the block, then $f_{ra}$ limiting value is $30N$ and $T_1$ doesn't kick in till $F = 15N$, so $f_{ra} = kt$ will $15/k.$ Then $T_1$ gets involved and $T_1$ is $kt-15.$

Comment: Hence now $ f_{ra} = 2kt-15$ for $t = 15/k$ to $30/k.$

Comment: Thanks Aadi..Is

Comment: Your handwriting is amazing, but you have to write it in mathjax.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem with this question is that it takes too long to get to the point. What you gotta do is, take the original question you made, and throw out all the details till you make a new question which is directly asking the last point you put, because that's the only one which matter. After you figure out the answer to the doubt you put at the end, try again this question. If you fail, see what step you get stuck with a doubt, and ask again.